Обнаружение и защита от DDoS атак средствами Python
Я написал скрипт, который слушает несколько открытых на роутере портов, и, когда получает от подключённого хоста какие-нибудь данные, отправляет их в телеграм канал.
Все работало нормально до момента пока кто-то не начал создавать огромное количество подключений и отправлять мусорные данные.
Процесс python.exe съел ресурсы процессора, поэтому его пришлось отключить.
По выводу в консоль, позже, я понял в чем было дело и задался вопросом, как от таких атак возможно защититься средствами python.
Пока из мыслей это собирать данные о подключении в массив, к каждому подключению добавлять временную метку и функцией проверять время между подключениям с одного хоста, если оно меньше секунды, то такой хост нужно отключать после срабатывания socket.accept()
Но когда мы приняли подключение, мы уже потратили некоторые ресурсы, и памяти и процессора.
Так что идея такая себе.
Есть у вас какие-либо варианты защиты получше ?

От настоящего DDoS защиты не бывает, а у вас невинные детские шалости какие-то

варианты защиты получше в вашем случае делаются средствами роутера. защита от подобных атак с помощью скриптового языка делает только хуже.

Да, это где-то раньше по цепочке нужно делать. Может ngnix какой-нибудь настроить соответственно. И да, включите авторизацию. Чтобы только авторизованное использование вашего API было возможно, а не кем ни попадя.

@CrazyElf, смысл приложения в том что кто ни попадя может подключаться ко мне, выше ответили что защита с помощью скриптового языка сделает только хуже, чем в этом плане лучше nginx ?
